# Rounded border - text input css

Tags: css

How can I add rounded borders to my text-type input?

For example: [image: search field with rounded borders]

I've tried css3 border but it gives a bad result.

Update: JS Solution: I'm still hoping to find a pure CSS-on-the-input solution, but here's the workaround I'll use for now. Please note this is pasted right out of my app so isn't a nice, stand-alone example like above. I've just included the relevant parts out of my large web app. You should be able to get the idea. The HTML is the input with the "link" class. The large vertical background position is because it's a sprite. Tested in IE6, IE7, IE8, FF2, FF3.5, Opera 9.6, Opera 10, Chrome 2, Safari 4. I need to tweak the background position a couple of pixels in some browsers still.

Comment: use `border-radius`!!

Answer (score 29):

```css
input[type=text]{
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
     border-radius: 20px;
     border: 1px solid #2d9fd9;
     color: #a0d18c;
     width: 250px;
     height: 30px;
     padding-left: 10px;
    }
    
input[type=text]:focus {
     outline: none;
     border: 1px solid #a0d18c;
     color: #2d9fd9;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter search text...">
```

Answer (score 16):

You want to look at `border-radius` ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) for further information)

> The border-radius CSS property allows Web authors to define how
>   rounded border corners are.

## **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suc3G/)**

```
input[type=text]{
  border-radius:10px;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Probably the only CSS solution. In older browsers you'll just get regular corners.
lol @ 10K party

Comment: As an addendum to the quotes issue, the CSS specs actually define them as optional for alphanumerics: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs

Answer (score 5):

[**http://jsfiddle.net/eeDAf/**](http://jsfiddle.net/eeDAf/)

```
border-radius: 7px;
```

it is really simple!